# Is macro more secure than static const if I don't want someone to know or change the hardcode value?

Tags: c++, c, security

I searched some topic about

```
#define PASSWORD "abcde"
```

and

```
static const char* PASSWORD="abcde";
```

It seems that `#define` does not store the value in memory (I am not sure if it is right). I heard it may have some tools can detect and access which memory address is using during app execution (e.g.:change some value for a game). I afraid, if I use `static const char* PASSWORD`, someone may know the value of PASSWORD by detecting the address of PASSWORD and get the value of PASSWORD by getting the content in the address.

Is it better to use `#define` if I want the hardcode value more safe?

Comment: You are not going to find a way of completely hiding it, use a hash function and compare hashes instead of passwords.

Comment: If the application is running on a machine you do not control there is no way to guarantee that the application will not be modified or "spied on". Whether you use a macro, a constant or a variable the data will still be present on disk and in memory at runtime.

Comment: You may as well use `static char PASSWORD[] = "abcde";` as it saves you the space for storing a pointer that you have no intention, it seems, of varying.

Answer (score 4):

Doesn't matter in this case. Since both use a string-literal, the string itself will be stored in the string pool, as opposed to existing somewhere dynamically on the heap. Also, macros *technically* don't even exist, since the compiler simply replaced all instances of the macro with the `#define` definition. During runtime, the program won't see a difference.

EDIT:
As someone mentioned, if you want to mess with security, look into [hashing](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hash_function). This would make it much more difficult to pull out the password with a memory-searching program.

Comment: What on earth is "the string pool"?

Comment: So, if you have a program that uses the string-literal `"hello world!"` multiple times, it's silly to have more than one copy of this string in memory. It's wasteful. So anytime you hard-define a string, your program will keep it in a place called the "string pool". This is simply a place that it keeps string-literals at, so that they can be used anytime they are referenced in your code. [This](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/String_interning) might explain it a little more.

Comment: Assuming the application is running on an end-user's machine (as per the author's game reference) hashing will only make it harder to find the actual value, if the string is long and "random" enough that the hash does not appear in ie. http://www.hashkiller.co.uk/

Comment: You are confusing Java and C++.

Comment: The site I posted references Java, however a string pool is definitely used in C. If you want to check this, create two different `char *myString = "Hello World!"`. They will have the same pointer address.

Comment: @cehnehdeh So long as they're in the same compilation unit, yes. Constant strings in separate files won't necessarily be unified, though.

Answer (score 0):

You may want to use you variable as constant expression.

```
constexp char* = "abc";
```

It is better than a define and the variable exists only at compile time, so the variable don't have any address at all. However, just like a define, it will print "abc" into the binary directly. You may want to mix this with hashing.